# R: parallelization with foreach

Tags: r, parallel-processing, domc, doparallel

I am new to R.  I've written this very simple script to highlight my problem.  If I run this regular for loop testdata is updated on each iteration just as I want it.

```
a = 5
b = 4
c = 3
testdata = matrix(nrow=100, ncol=5)
for(j in 1:100){
testdata[j,1] <- a*j
testdata[j,2] <- b*j
testdata[j,3] <- c*j
testdata[j,4] <- (a+b)*j
testdata[j,5] <- (a+c)*j
}
```

However this parallel version using foreach completes the computations but they are not updated in testdata.

```
a = 5
b = 4
c = 3
testdata = matrix(nrow=100, ncol=5)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
getDoParWorkers()  # Checking the number of cores. 

foreach(j = 1:100) %dopar% {
  testdata[j,1] <- a*j
  testdata[j,2] <- b*j
  testdata[j,3] <- c*j
  testdata[j,4] <- (a+b)*j
  testdata[j,5] <- (a+c)*j
}
```

I have attempted to follow examples here and elsewhere on the internet but most of the examples were too deep in R shoptalk and I couldn't follow.  How can I make this parallel version do what the non-parallel version does.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the `.combine` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the docs for the `foreach` package. In the `foreach(j = 100)` section of your code, you can specify the argument `.combine` to tell `foreach` how to compile your results. Since you want a 5x100 data frame/matrix, you would logically write a vector of your five arguments (i.e. `c(a*j, b*j, c*j, (a+b)*j, (a+c)*j)`), and `rbind` them to make a single data frame. Check out my code below:

```
a = 5
b = 4
c = 3

library(foreach)
library(doParallel) 
library(parallel)

## Assuming you want to use all of your cores
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())

## Specify your .combine argument below
foreach(j = 1:100, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
    c(a*j, b*j, c*j, (a+b)*j, (a+c)*j)
}
```

And this spits out:

```
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
result.1      5    4    3    9    8
result.2     10    8    6   18   16
result.3     15   12    9   27   24
result.4     20   16   12   36   32
result.5     25   20   15   45   40
...
```

You could then take this one step further by assigning this to the variable you want:

```
...
testdata <- foreach(j = 1:100, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
                c(a*j, b*j, c*j, (a+b)*j, (a+c)*j)
            }
testdata <- as.data.frame(testdata, row.names = FALSE)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beautiful!  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!